# MFC executing thread problems

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

I have a CDialog that allow users to navigate, listing and showing files preview in the hard disk. In some cases there might be a lot of heavy files and these cases require a lot of time, so we moved the loading operations in a separate thread.

Now, I expect that moving disk accesses in a separate thread would have let me to use the CDialog normally, but this does not happen so I can't scroll or move the window.

Am I missing something in the process? Here's the code:

```
void CMyDialog::LoadFiles()
{
    // …
    std::thread load_file(LoadingRoutine, reinterpret_cast<void *>(&data));
    load_file.detach();
    // same happens if I use Afx functions
    // AfxBeginThread(&CMyDialog::LoadingRoutine, reinterpret_cast<void *>(&data));
    // …
}
```

Comment: That's not nearly enough to pinpoint the issue. Where does the code hang, when you break into the debugger? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: The code *does not* hang: simply I can't use the dialog untile the thread finishes its job.

Comment: Seems like 'data' is a shared resource and used elsewhere in the dialog . Use std::promise and std::future to get status of the thread. If future is not ready, signal the dialog to print other message and proceed.

Comment: _Am I missing something_ Yes! As IInspectable says, we need a [MCVE] - something we can inspect, compile, run and test for ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

Problem partially fixed: it seems that using threads prevents the window to consume messages regularly even if it's a non-blocking call.

My workaround consisted in giving the control back to window to let it to consume messages:

```
// … thread stuff
for (auto nI = 0; nI < nCount; nI++)
{
     // Heavy computing
     nSleepStep = 5;
     nSleepTime = 200;
     while (nSleepTime > nSleepStep)
     {
          while(PeekMessage(&msg, hWnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
          {
             switch( msg.message ) 
             { 
             case WM_TIMER : 
             case WM_PAINT :
               TranslateMessage( &msg );
               DispatchMessage( &msg );
               break;
             }
         }
         std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(nSleepStep));
         nSleepTime -= nSleepStep;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to use `AfxBeginThread` or `std::thread::detach`. You will be able to use the dialog in the main UI thread normally.

Alternatively you can do this in a single thread, assuming your function can be interrupted and broken in to different parts. For example, lets say you have function that takes 3 seconds to complete:

```
Sleep(3000);
```

It can be broken in to 30 parts and simulated as

```
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) 
    Sleep(100);
```

You can update paint after each move. Note that other dialog messages must be ignored, because this is a single thread and you can only do one thing at a time. You should disable the controls to let the user know the dialog is busy. Example:

```
void update_paint()
{
    MSG msg;
    while(PeekMessage(&msg, m_hWnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        if(msg.message == WM_COMMAND && msg.wParam == IDCANCEL) { }//cancel reuested
        if(msg.message == WM_PAINT ||
            (msg.message >= WM_NCCALCSIZE && msg.message <= WM_NCACTIVATE) ||
            (msg.message >= WM_NCMOUSEMOVE && msg.message <= WM_NCMBUTTONDBLCLK))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
}

void CMyDialog::single_thread()
{
    MessageBox(L"start");
    //disable child controls to let user know the dialog is busy
    for(CWnd *p = GetWindow(GW_CHILD); p; p = p->GetWindow(GW_HWNDNEXT))
        p->EnableWindow(FALSE);

    for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        Sleep(100);
        update_paint();
    }

    //enable child controls
    for(CWnd *p = GetWindow(GW_CHILD); p; p = p->GetWindow(GW_HWNDNEXT))
        p->EnableWindow(TRUE);
    MessageBox(L"done");
}
```

If the function cannot be interrupted then launching a second thread is necessary.